# What terminology is used for English words coined by EFL speakers?

Tags: terminology, neologisms

A *neologism* is a newly coined word. Is there a term for a new English-language word coined by people in another country for whom English is a foreign language? While visiting China a few years ago, some Chinese friends introduced me to their new word -- *gelivable.* At first I thought they were mispronouncing or mangling *believable,* but they explained that it was a word for saying that something was sufficient or enough or adequate. A bit of research reveals that the word is formed from a Chinese word, *geili.* http://www.china.org.cn/china/2010-11/12/content_21327924.htm

I see the word described as a Net buzzword. A Google Ngram Viewer search yielded zero hits.

My question is: what terminology is used for this kind of formation of an English (or at least English-sounding) word that seems to be used primarily, if not exclusively by people whose first language is not English?

Comment: I edited your posting just now so that it explicitly states that you had already been *living in China* for several years by the time your Chinese friends introduced you to *gelivable*. If this isn't what you meant, please feel free to amend my edit as necessary.

Comment: Ngram is only going to show material from books, no?

Comment: @ Erik Kowal, actually I was only there for a short visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such words are known as *loanwords*. In the case of 'gelivable', the loanword is an *anglicism* (because it is patterned on English morphology).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a good term for these words in general, but there are a number for words from speaks of a specific foreign language:

- *Wasei-eigo* (home-made English) for Japanese neologisms coined from English words.
- *Denglish* for German-origin (Deutsch) neologisms.
- *Franglais* for French-origin neologisms.

Sometimes the umbrella term *Engrish* or *Engrishisms* is used for these foreign neologisms, especially ones originating from Northwest Asia, but this is borderline offensive and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Franglais typically refers not to a word that is introduced into English from French, but an English word (or a word derived from an English word) that is introduced into French. "Apres-ski" is not Franglais; "weekend" is franglais.

Comment: By "French-origin neologisms" I mean "French neologisms coined from English words."

Answer (score 1):

A **paronymous neologism** may suffice, though I've never actually heard the term used:

[**paronymous:**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paronymous)

> 2a) formed from a word in another language
>
> 2b) having a form similar to that of a cognate foreign word